# How to bind DataContext to ViewModel object in window resources

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datacontext

I'm trying to bind my usercontrol datacontext to the viewmodel object. For unknown reason setting the DataContext inside the Window.Resources as a result gives

> System.Windows.Data Error: 3 : Cannot find element that provides
>   DataContext. BindingExpression:Path=AreaFilter; DataItem=null;

setting the same datacontext outside of the window.resources works perfect. Piece of code should clear the things up:

```
<Window>
<Window.Resources>
    <GridViewColumnCollection x:Key="eventColumns">
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Area}">
            <GridViewColumn.Header>
                <v:FilterV DataContext="{Binding AreaFilter}"/> <!--here is the problem-->
            </GridViewColumn.Header>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridViewColumnCollection>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <v:FilterV DataContext="{Binding AreaFilter}"/> <!-- here it works OK -->
    <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Name="listHeader" Columns="{StaticResource eventColumns}"/>
</Grid>
```

FilterV is a UserControl that I simplified currently to show just a textblock.
Inside a Grid it shows the AreaFilter.Name with no problem.
What's the difference when setting the DataContext in these two situations and how to solve that?

Comment: Binding used like this referes to another DataContext. So even if you set the DataContext, you need to have another valid DataContext to get the property AreaFilter from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `GridViewColumn` is not actually part of the `VisualTree`, so bindings in it won't work because it doesn't have a `DataContext` or source to use when evaluating the bindings.

You can try setting the `DataContext` with a `RelativeSource` binding that references your `GridView`

```
<GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <v:FilterV DataContext="{Binding DataContext.AreaFilter, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GridView}}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

Although if that doesn't work the only workaround I've found is to create a [Freezeable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx) object in your `.Resources` containing the binding you're looking for, then setting your `v:FilterV.DataContext` to the static resource

```
<GridView.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" 
        Data="{Binding AreaFilter, ElementName=MyGridView}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>

...

<GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <v:FilterV DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

You can view an example of this [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)

Also, you should set the `GridViewHeaderTemplate` property to a `DataTemplate` containing your `<v:FilterV />` control instead of setting it directly in the `.Content` property like you have it now. Setting the `Content` directly to an object means that any item that uses that style will try to use the same controls in the `Content`, so if you have more than one object that applies that `Content` property it will throw an exception because items can only belong to one parent control

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it clearly. I'm trynig to use <v:FilterV> in different columns (in the exaple I simplified the code) and in every column it has to bind to a different object. That's why I'm trying to set DataContext in the ColumnCollection. If I define a DataTemplate that will contain v:FilterV I don't know where to bind different VM objects to each FilterV.

Comment: Good timing, this seems similar to the question I just asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398419/datacontext-not-binding-in-style-trigger).  Hopefully your answer can shed some light on my issue!