# DataContext not binding in Style.Trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, datacontext

So I have some code similar to the following: (Forgive any typos-- I tried to simplify in the SO editor for the post)

```
<my:CustomContentControl>
        <my:CustomContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:CustomContentControl}">
                <Style.Triggers>                        
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentView}" Value="MyCustomView">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <my:CustomView DataContext="{Binding DataContextForMyCustomView"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </m:CustomContentControl.Style>
</my:CustomContentControl>
```

The problem is that whenever the `DataTrigger` occurs, the setter **does** set the `Content` property to `my:CustomView`, but it **does not** bind `DataContext`.  If I move the same code outside of the trigger the `DataContext` binding works just fine.

Any ideas?  If this is a limitation of some sorts, is there any work around?

**Update:**

I received the following error in the output window:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 3 : Cannot find element that provides DataContext. BindingExpression:Path=DataContextForMyCustomView; DataItem=null; target element is 'CustomView' (Name='customView'); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')`

Comment: Do you have any error or warning message about this binding in your output window?

Comment: @Miklós: Great suggestion, thanks.  Duh, it slipped my mind that binding errors show up in the output window!  Updating my question w/ the error now...

Comment: @HolySamosa What is your `UserControl` in? The error you posted makes it sound like it's in an object that doesn't have a `DataContext`, such as a `DataGridColumn.Header`. Also, you really should use `ContentTemplate` instead of `Content` to avoid an exception if more than one object applies that style :)

Comment: @Rachel: The user control is a MVVM View I've created. Also, I tried to sanitize my example code to leave out the specifics of my implementation. The ContentControl I'm using is actually a custom control from MahApps that handles transitions. I'm trying to use the BindingProxy from the article you linked to in your answer to Bartek's question. I seem to be making progress with it.  (I deleted my earlier comment as I was trying to do something braindead. :-)

Comment: @Rachel: Yep, Thomas Levesque's [BindingProxy](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/#comment-2214) solved my problem.  Thanks!  If you'd like to leave an answer with a link to the article, I'd be happy to award you the correct answer!

Comment: @HolySamosa Sure, I copied it into an answer and expanded it a bit to include some code samples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you posted makes it sound like your custom control is in an object that doesn't have a `DataContext`, such as a `DataGridColumn.Header`.

To get around that, you can create a [Freezeable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx) object in your `.Resources` containing the binding you're looking for, then bind your `my:CustomView.DataContext` to that object

```
<my:CustomContentControl.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" 
        Data="{Binding DataContextForMyCustomView, ElementName=MyControl}" />
</my:CustomContentControl.Resources>

...

<my:CustomView DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
```

Here's the code for a sample `Freezable` object copied from [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/):

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), 
            typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Also, you really should use `ContentTemplate` instead of `Content` to avoid an exception if more than one object applies that style :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by putting the UserControl into the resources and then changing the Content with that.

e.g. from my own code (different names, same concept)

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="7,0,7,0">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <mapping:Slide11x4MappingView x:Key="Slide11X4MappingView" DataContext="{Binding MappingViewModel}"/>
        <mapping:MicrotubeMappingView x:Key="MicrotubeMappingView"  DataContext="{Binding MappingViewModel}"/>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Acquirer.Sorter.TrayType}" Value="{x:Static mapping:TrayType.SLIDES11X4}">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource Slide11X4MappingView}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Acquirer.Sorter.TrayType}" Value="{x:Static mapping:TrayType.VIALS}">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource MicrotubeMappingView}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```